# ScriptWitnessNotValidatingUTXOW while trying to mint NFT in preprod testnet

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet, cardano-node

minting script

```
    "type": "all",
    "scripts":
    [   
        {
            "type": "after",
            "slot": 155761
        },
        {
            "type": "sig",
            "keyHash": "e9ce8633aef95b632bfbffc12a83cc4c589132c46cd03f8dae146ec2"
        }
     
    ]
}
```

metadata-json-file

```
    "721": {
        "ca8fc6bf8d698d5752e6c700c8a5818c2abe5a17877121ae99604e24": {
            "cat": {
                "name": "Nikki",
                "image": ["ipfs://QmQQqHaitxGkzNTRCSxJxTU5JaVvSoGGxocBcU246BZA7M"],
                "mediaType": "image/png",
                "description": "remember when?",
                "files": [
                    {
                        "mediaType": "image/png",
                        "src": ["ipfs://QmQQqHaitxGkzNTRCSxJxTU5JaVvSoGGxocBcU246BZA7M"]
                    },
                    {
                        "mediaType": "image/png",
                        "src": ["ipfs://QmYCbn5Nj3Xq28QwDkerMBAXsLBDa26f1k8jruuKn5gzXn"]
                    }
                    
                ],
                "type": "Nadan",
                "color": "white and brown"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

cardano-cli query tip --testnet-magic 1

```
{
    "block": 153845,
    "epoch": 19,
    "era": "Alonzo",
    "hash": "789909e77ba308c069b0e09809a6ec7508da0d2c0c474565caed2688afe3618e",
    "slot": 6674546,
    "syncProgress": "100.00"
}
```

command line variables

```
POLICYID=ca8fc6bf8d698d5752e6c700c8a5818c2abe5a17877121ae99604e24
TXIN="02a037b9649eb62f17549bf33114763568b59a4be20beba6132f7b996a0825e2#0"
TOKENNAME1="6e696b6b69"
POLICYSCRIPT="ppbl-nft-2.script"
MINTER=addr_test1vr5uap3n4mu4kcetl0luz25re3x93yfjc3kdq0ud4c2xassvq0wsd
METADATA_JSON_FILE="mynft.json"
RECIEVER=addr_test1qzdquurtx940tpyfgt7pu2h8zgrgfepf7quwcqqh3kmacd83z2naq8a2cltaqyxexml30wh77uyu3sll7feyp2nzqgnqfdpnsa
```

// transaction `cardano-cli transaction build \ --alonzo-era \ --testnet-magic 1 \ --tx-in $TXIN \ --tx-out $RECIEVER+1500000+"1 $POLICYID.$TOKENNAME" \ --change-address $MINTER \ --mint "1 $POLICYID.$TOKENNAME" \ --minting-script-file ppbl-nft-2.script \ --metadata-json-file mynft.json \ --protocol-params-file protocol.json \ --out-file nft.raw`

//transaction sign

```
cardano-cli transaction sign \
--signing-key-file payment.skey \
--testnet-magic 1 \
--tx-body-file nft.raw \
--out-file mint-nft.signed
```

//submit transaction

```
cardano-cli transaction submit \
--tx-file mint-nft.signed \
--testnet-magic 1
```

ERROR

```
Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (ScriptWitnessNotValidatingUTXOW (fromList [ScriptHash "c867c502e249d681b35a8df2e3df5e58ec2c16d3df445429484a1793"])))])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using,

```
{
    "type": "after",
    "slot": 155761
}
```

while the current slot on preprod is `~154042`. This policy allows using it only **after** slot `155761`, for more info see [(1)](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/reference/simple-scripts.md). Also make sure that,

```
cardano-cli address key-hash --payment-verification-key-file payment.skey
```

is equal to `e9ce8633aef95b632bfbffc12a83cc4c589132c46cd03f8dae146ec2`.

Comment: i changes the script ``` {
    "type": "all",
    "scripts":
    [   
        {
            "type": "after",
            "slot": 6702243
        },
        {
            "type": "sig",
            "keyHash": "e9ce8633aef95b632bfbffc12a83cc4c589132c46cd03f8dae146ec2"
        }
     
    ]
}``` and key hash is also the same still same error

Comment: Hmm, that's weird, I also think I had the slot of preprod wrong (your query is correct).

Comment: Can you use the `--invalid-after` to make the transaction valid even if it is send before the `after` slot?

Comment: ``` cardano-cli transaction build \
--alonzo-era \
--testnet-magic 1 \
--tx-in $TXIN \
--tx-out $RECIEVER+1500000+"1 $POLICYID.$TOKENNAME" \
--change-address $MINTER \
--mint "1 $POLICYID.$TOKENNAME" \
--minting-script-file ppbl-nft-2.script \
--invalid-hereafter 6753799 \
--metadata-json-file mynft.json \
--protocol-params-file protocol.json \
--out-file nft.raw```

Comment: still same error

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `--invalid-before` flag when building the transaction. It sets the lower bound of the transaction's validity interval, which is required for the script to determine whether the interval range is greater than slot 155761. You must use a slot that is lower than the current slot.